# how to apply filter, when i click the form in blankformList Activity only that form entries visible to user in InsctanceChooserList Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYbOI.png) find this

Comment: Please don't post code images or bugs if possible, copy your code or code error into question with block code format: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry but i dint have error i dont know how implement this thats  why i am sharing my code

Comment: Please do not post images of code, copy your code into the question with block code format:   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask